# Laravel Validator unique with condition

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I'm having trouble getting the Validator to work with the rule that I want to set up. I could have made multiple tables, but it's going to be a lot of work to undo everything, so I'd prefer to make it work if possible.

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'segment_name' => [
          'required',
        Rule::unique('groups')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('lang', $list_name)->where('group_type', 'auto_segment');
      }),
    ],
  ]);
```

I thought query was the way to do it, but I now realise that this adds another constraint instead. What I want is the validation to fail when the 2 query conditions are met, but otherwise then it should pass. Is there any easy way to do this?

---

After spending more time working on this, I've made some more attempts, but it hasn't yet worked. Using 2 rules, the validator fails when I would want it to pass, similar to using || in an if statement instead of &&. Using a pipe between the two rules failed and generated an offset error, but this might not have been correct.

```
'segment_name' => 'unique:groups,segment_name,NULL,id,lang,' . $list_name,
'segment_name' => 'unique:groups,segment_name,NULL,id,group_type,auto_segment'

'segment_name' => 'unique:groups,segment_name,NULL,id,lang,' . $list_name . '|unique:groups,segment_name,NULL,id,group_type,auto_segment'
```

After finally getting the original query to work without variables, ended up using a global variable to pass to the query, as a local wouldn't work.

Comment: create a custom validation and pass it with validation like required seperated by pipeline.you will get value of segment and can manipulate as u like to give true or false.

Comment: I was looking at custom validation and Complex Conditional Validation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique, and I feel that I've almost got it, but not quite. Thanks, I'll have another try at it.

Comment: It turns out the original code, does what I wanted it to, and there was a problem with the input. Thanks for comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

For unique you can do like this -

```
$rules = [
    'segment_name' => 'required|unique', // you can unique validate like this also 'unique:tablename', for specific table 
];

//Validate inputs
$input = Input::only('segment_name');

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was able to have the input as unique, using similar to this method, but I only want it to be unique if these conditions are met ->where('lang', $list_name)->where('group_type', 'auto_segment')

Comment: ok, but i guess through validator it won't be possible. You can check  it through query.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. I had it set up with Validator before, but then changed the table, but didn't want to change it if it wasn't needed.